# IntelliJでコンパイルレベルの指定

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJでライブラリを作っているのですが、
SDKにはJava8を使用して、コンパイルレベルはJava7で行いたいです。
ですが、いくら設定をしても、絶対にJava8でコンパイルされてしまいます。

設定は　Project language level　を　7　にしています。
（モジュールも）

Artifact　で　jar　を出力しています。
出力後の　jar　を分解して　class　をのぞいてもやはり　major52（Java8）　としてコンパイルされています。

どうすれば　Java８SDK を使用して　Java7 の　jar を出力できるのでしょうか？

Comment: Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler にあるProject bytecode version は何になっているでしょうか？
あと、IntelliJのバージョンも教えてもらえますか？

Comment: 回答有り難うございますProject bytecode versionには何も設定されていなくて何も表示されていない状態でした
もしかしてこちらを設定する必要があったのでしょうか？


IntelliJはMac版の最新版14.1.5です

Comment: 回答のほうに書きましたが、 Per-module bytecode versionに1.7を指定すればJava7のclassになると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project bytecode versionに1.7を指定して、その下の Per-module bytecode version にモジュールを追加、そのモジュールのTarget bytecode versionを1.7に指定すればJava7のclassになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます
支持された方法でできました！
（モジュールの方だけでしてみました）

では、私の設定したあの項目は一体何なんでしょうね…